# How can I convert this Excel graph data into a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql

I have a 3 axis cylinder graph in Excel which is generated from a pivot table sourced from a SQL DB table.  Currently, Excel is simply pulling **all** the data from the SQL table into a pivot table to generate the datasource behind the graph.  I would like to use a T-SQL query to pull only the data needed to generate a similar graph outside of Excel (in Javascript to be precise).  The graph looks like so:

[image: Cylinder graph]

And the SQL table column structure is as follows (terrible schema, I know):

- EntryID
- Operator
- Date_Year
- Date_Month
- Date_Day
- Various other items (irrelevant for generating the graph)

So far I've been able to use code to pull the data needed to populate the source outside of Excel, though this generates 122 separate queries--clearly unacceptable.  The way I'm doing it in the code is by selecting all distinct Date_Years, Date_Months, and Date_Operators like so:

- `SELECT DISTINCT Date_Year from dbo.Items`
- `SELECT DISTINCT Date_Month from dbo.Items`
- `SELECT DISTINCT Operator from dbo.Items`

Then iterating through the years, months, and operators.  I'm looking for a way to pull all this data in as little queries as possible, rather than iterating and repeatedly hitting the DB server.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated--please let me know if further clarification is necessary.  Thanks!

Comment: You can select more than one column in a select statement...

Comment: How is it figuring out the height of the bars in the graph? Is it counting something? Summing something?

Comment: Look at the raw data in the pivot table. Excel has an algorithm to figure out how high to make its charts based on the data given it.

Comment: Oh, and your chart says "Count of Operator" therefore it is counting operators.

Comment: Is the list of months and years constant or does it change? (Does it always run from February 2013 thru June 2014?)

Comment: Becuzz--the height is the number of entries for each year, month and operator.  And the list does change which is why I'm using the DISTINCT for each month and year and iterating.  I think Rowland's answer is pointing me in a good direction!

Comment: Becuzz & Jeremy--thanks for the help but as it turns out Rowland's answer was perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, Excel is grouping the values up in some way, so in your graph, it appears to be grouped by year, month and operator, with an aggregation for the values. Essentially it is doing something similar to:

```
SELECT      Date_Year,
            Date_Month,
            Operator,
            COUNT(*) AS Value

FROM        dbo.Items

GROUP BY    Date_Year,
            Date_Month,
            Operator
```

Of course, you could tweak that to suit with `WHERE` clauses or changing the aggregate function, but you might want to start with that...